# How to call bash from Qt creator on windows 10

Tags: qt-creator, bash-on-windows

I have Qt Creator 4.4.1 installed on Windows 10 64 bit. I have also `bash on ubuntu on windows` installed. I want to call `bash` from Qt creator in order to execute some linux commands on the project directory by creating a custom building process step but unfortunately I get the following error:

```
16:21:50: Running steps for project myTest...
16:21:50: Could not start process "bash" foamExec
Error while building/deploying project myTest (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.3 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "Custom Process Step"
16:21:50: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

I have also tried the following steps:

To specify the full path of `bash`: `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` but it fails with the
   same error.

To call `cmd` to execute a .bat script that contains the
   following code: `bash -c "my command that I want to execute"` but I get the following error as well:

```
``16:30:31: Running steps for project myTest...
16:30:31: Starting: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "bash -c 'foamExec wmake'"
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
16:30:31: The process "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
Error while building/deploying project myTest (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.3 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "Custom Process Step"``.
```

I tried to create external commands in Qt from: **Tools** > **External**, but I get always the same error.

I tried also to run Qt creator from bash terminal: `"/mnt/c/Qt/Qt5.9.3/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator.exe"` Qt Creator starts fine but again it doesn't recognize `bash` command.

.
Can you please explain me why Qt Creator cannot recognize `bash`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but maybe someone will figure out the rest.

The "bash not recognized" part is because of [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1105) - basically, Qt is a 32-bit application, while bash.exe is a 64-bit application, and since Qt's cmd is 32-bit, it cannot find it.

However, addressing this introduces a different error. I've tried the following:

- Running bash directly, using "C:\Windows\sysnative\bash.exe" path
- Wrapping bash in 64-bit cmd.exe (run "C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /C bash")
- Wrapping bash in 32-bit cmd.exe (run "cmd /C C:\Windows\sysnative\bash.exe")

Neither of the above work, instead failing with  "The process exited with code -1". This happens even with a 64-bit version of QtCreator - it seems that there's something about WSL that prevents it from running inside QtCreator.